# how to avoid new line while saving file in windows python 3.3 IDLE?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-idle, windowserror

I'm newbie to python. As I start coding simple python code using windows Python 3.3.3 Shell, when I try to save webtest1.py, it automatically adds extra line below. While running the code, this automatically causes `invalid syntax` error.

I check the code online on http://pych.atomidata.com/code, it shows, 'Line: 8 Column: 1 W391 blank line at end of file'.

Any solution? 
Appreciated.

[image: saving .py file with new line automatic addition error]

Comment: `print` is a function in Python3.

Comment: so how to re-write the above code? I mean, I use print to check the content of the generated output file. BTW, it doesn't help in any case. :(

Comment: `print(htmltext)`, and never post screenshots in question body.

Comment: Thank you. So the print command difference from Python 2.x to 3.x is: print some_text to print (some_text)

Comment: Yes, [Print Is A Function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets around `print` in python 3.  `print (htmltext)` should solve your problem.

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print

Edit: @Ashwini already stated that until I wrote this. I think you/he should write that in answers so it can be accepted.